# Windows XP SP3 command prompt can't detect PATH

Tags: windows, path, command-prompt, ping, windows-xp-sp3

tally ho.

I'm using Windows XP Professional 2002 Service Pack 3

I've been trying to ping websites, but when I try to ping anything it returns:

```
'PING' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

A bit of research tells me it's because I don't have a PATH set, so I set the PATH at My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables
Both user and system as 'C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem'

I restarted the command prompt and nothing changed. I checked the registry on regedit and the PATH is the same as above.

When I entered 'set' on command prompt, it returns:

```
PATH=
COMSPEC=\COMMAND.COM
```

And when I entered echo %PATH%, it only returns '%PATH$'

When I entered cd, it returns CD:\DOCUME~1\PERSONAL

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: It's 2017 as I write this. Why are you using Windows XP Professional 2002 Service Pack 3?  Plus your title doesn't match.

Comment: @Tony It's actually the PC my parents are using. We haven't bought new OS since they're prohibitively expensive and it doesn't seem necessary for their browsing needs.

Comment: Is it possible that `ping.exe` is actually missing?

Comment: You could actually type in the command with the full path, for instance: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\ping.exe` (if it's actually there)